# Git diff to see lines that have NOT been modified?

Tags: git

I basically want the opposite of `git diff`. I want a way to see the lines that have not been modified/removed etc. Is this possible through the CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe tools like tortoise-diff show all lines, if you want to see unchanged ones then just ignore the highlighted ones. in what case are unchanged lines interesting anyway?

Comment: I have two instances of a dependency file and I want to see which dependencies are in the same version. Most of them have changed, so it's easier to find the ones that stayed the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a ridiculously large value for `-U` and then filter out the lines which contain differences.

```sh
git diff -U20000 | grep -v '^[-+]'
```

This still fails to show files which don't contain any differences, though.  You could `diff` against the original check-in to force all files to have changes, but that's not always what you want, either.